# Comparing two set of data : formated and text

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet nammed "unformated" containing 20 column and 40 row of data.
All the cell are unformated, so "text".

I have another worksheet nammed "formated" containing the same 20 column / 40 row, but all the cell are correctly formated.

Meaning for exemple that if a cell contain "2023/02/07", in "unformated" worksheet it's type is "text" and in "formated" it's type is "date" with "yyyy/mm/dd" format.

The format is completly unpredictable (sometime "yyyy/mm/dd", "yyyy mm", "# ##0,00", "# ##0" ...), but my task is to make sure that the two worksheet are identical.

If I use the formula `=IF(unformated!A2 <> formated!A2; "NOT THE SAME"; "")`, then I get the wrong result.

The thing is that I have "a lot" of worksheet comparison to do, and some worksheet can contain "a lot" of row/line, so it's not possible to manually convert all cell.
I'm not used to Excel but I can't believe there is nothing to compare the visual representation of a cell.

How can I compare the two set ?

Comment: Did you try something like: `=--unformated!A2 =-- formated!A2`? (where `--` converts text to numeric.

Comment: @P.b No, I didn't knew `--` existance. I just tried, but for some cell with the same representation, I got `#VALUE!`.
Surprisingly enougth, the format is ";;" (I would have expected "Text", but well, I don't manage the format)

Comment: `--` converts text to number value in case possible. If not it throws an error. You could take advantage of that using `=IFERROR(--unformated!A2,unformated!A2)=IFERROR(--formatted!A2,formatted!A2)`